# Поиск упорядоченного группового диапазона введённого float

Tags: память, lua

Для одной игры я делаю lua скрипт для game guardian который меняет transform.scale объекта. Просто так найти объект и изменить размер нельзя. Для начала нужно найти объект: единственный отличительный признак любого объекта это позиция X Y Z. По этому искать структуру объекта я буду по упорядоченному групповому поиску. Однако игра показывает позицию объекта с точностью до двух знаков после запятой, а что бы найти значение нужно больше точности, соответственно значение не может быть найдено. По этому придется использовать упорядоченный групповой поиск диапазона.
Например:

```
gg.setRanges(gg.REGION_ANONYMOUS)
gg.searchNumber("12.6347;52.6917;24.5093:9", gg.TYPE_FLOAT)
```

Однако мне не известный последние две цифры, по этому искать придется так:

```
gg.setRanges(gg.REGION_ANONYMOUS)
gg.searchNumber("12.62~12.64;52.68~52.70;24.49~24.51:9", gg.TYPE_FLOAT)
```

Ну а теперь у меня есть три переменные с вводом пользователя:
73.28, 91.63, 13.57. Как сделать по этим числам упорядоченный групповой поиск диапазона как я описал выше?

Comment: в чем трудность, не понятно, проходите в трех вложенных циклах по переменным, типа `for x=12.6200, 12.6400, 0.0001 do` внутри искать по значениям..